# How do you ignore a line of string text when reading a text file in Java?

Tags: java

In my program, I have to read a text file where the first line will have a string with text, and the following line/lines will have integers.  I need to be able to read the first string, ignore it, and then continue reading the integers in order to do calculations.  I am unsure of how to read the first string of text and disregard it and continue reading the next line of integers.

For this program, I can't use arrays or the try...catch methods to solve.  I must only use while loops and for loops and if-else statements as well.

This is the code I have so far.  It reads the text file entered, but I cannot get it to ignore the string of text and move on to the numbers.  I'm not sure what to put in my while loop to get it to work correctly.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Homework7_56299 {

    //displays program purpose and asks user to enter a file name
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This program reads a number file and prints the statistics");
        System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");

        String fileName;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        processFile(fileName);
    }   

    //this method reads the file and calculates the statistics
    public static void processFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double sum = 0.0;
        int count = 0;

        File file = new File(fileName);
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        String str = null;

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {

            if (inputFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                System.out.println();
            }

            if (inputFile.hasNextInt())
            {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
                System.out.println(num);
            }


        }
        inputFile.close();

    }
```

Comment: Reading in a line and ignoring it is really no more complicated than calling the `nextLine();` method of your Scanner and simply doing nothing with the return result.

Comment: What *are* your calculations btw?

Comment: My calculations will be finding the average, smallest, and largest number, and the count of numbers that are above the average and below the average.  I am currently trying to write a for loop to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As the one in your comments already mentioned, it's enough for you to just put the following code before your while loop:

```
// Ignore the first line (string) by reading it and not doing anything with it
if (inputFile.hasNextLine()) 
{
   inputFile.nextLine();
}
```

In this case "ignoring the first line" would mean that it reads the first line, but doesn't do anything with it - that should be working for you.

Regarding the inputFile.hasNextInt() - Part of your code - just a tip:

You are currently reading the whole line and converting it to an integer. It would also work for you, if you just use

```
if (inputFile.hasNextInt()) 
{
  System.out.println(inputFile.nextInt());
}
```

This handles the conversion automatically for you, so you dont have to read the line and convert it to an Integer in an own step.

Keep coding, your code looks good :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked!  Now I have to figure out how to write the for loop to calculate avg, smallest number, largest number, and the count of numbers above and below the avg.

Comment: You got this. I will give you the solution, but I'd advise you to try to figure it out on your own. First of all - in your while () loop, you will just add some checks and override some variables. 1) You have your current number - just check if its smaller than your current smallest number - if yes, this is your new smallest number. 2) Add the same check, just for the largest number. 3) In every loop you add +1 to your count - variable. 4) In every loop you also add the current number to your sum. 5) After the loop, you just print out your variables - thats it.